# Spring Batch - getLastJobExecution() with sub-set of JobParameters?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch application which run a DB reading/writing job on a cron schedule. I want to cover the scenario where the application maybe stopped for 4 hours, and when it next runs it should use the start timestamp of the last job to determine the data it processes.

I have this code which registers the distinct job parameters, setting a new 'jobID' parameter each time.

```
@Override
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 */1 * * ?")
public JobExecution startJob(String cdmrJob,String jobType) {
    // lookup the job via the spring context or factory
    Job job = applicationContext.getBean(cdmrJob.getJobBeanName(), Job.class);

    String jobId = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addString("jobName", job.getName(),true)
            .addDate("jobDate", new Date(),false)
            .addString("jobUuid", UUID.randomUUID().toString(),false)
            .addString("jobID", jobId, true)
            .addString("jobType", jobType.name(),true)
            .toJobParameters();
    // get the last jobs start time if present..
    getLastJobExecution(cdmrJob,jobType);
    log.info("startJob({})",cdmrJob,StructuredArguments.entries(param.getParameters()));
    JobExecution jobExecution = null;
    try {
        jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
....
```

and then I have this code which uses the 'jobRepository' to search for the last instance of the matching job

```
@Override
public JobExecution getLastJobExecution(String cdmrJob,String jobType) {
    // match the job name and type
    Map<String, JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("jobName", new JobParameter(cdmrJob.getBatchJobName(), true));
    parameters.put("jobType", new JobParameter(jobType.name(), true));
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(parameters);
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobRepository.getLastJobExecution(cdmrJob.getBatchJobName(),jobParameters);
    log.info("/getLastJobExecution{}->{}",param,jobExecution);
    return jobExecution;
}
```

The problem is the 'jobExecution' is always null, since it seems 'jobRepository.getLastJobExecution' can't match the sub-set of job parameters.

When i set the 'jobID' parameter to be non-identiying the 'getLastJobExecution()' method matches and returns, but the batch complains that a completed job cannot be restarted.

Without reverting to writing a JDBC sql query - is there an approach via the batch API to run this type of sub-job parameter search?

I have seen these questions

- [Querying Spring Batch JobExecution with Batch Param values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63064254/querying-spring-batch-jobexecution-with-batch-param-values)
- [Spring Batch Job taking previous execution parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56524514/spring-batch-job-taking-previous-execution-parameters)